# Javascript : changing a value of element html

Tags: javascript, html

how can change the value of the first price span using javascript

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-27">
    <span class="price">$2,699.99</span>  
</span>


<span class="price">$2,000</span>
```

i've tried with getElementByClassName but it change for the tow of them

i want just to change the value of the first one `<span class="price">$2,699.99</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which first gets the outer span element, then all the elements within it with that class...

```
 var outerSpan = document.getElementById("product-price-27");
 var innerSpans = outerSpan.getElementsByClassName("price");
 innerSpans[0].innerHTML = "$xxxx";
```

Here is a [live JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnLP/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WLEAS/)</kbd>

`getElementsByClassName("price")` - Get all element, whose class name `price`

`[0]` - Its take first element of `price` class.

#### JavaScript

```
 var newprice = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerHTML = "$3,000.00";    // Assign New Value $3,000.00
```

#### HTML

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-27">
    <span class="price">$2,699.99</span>  
</span>
<br />

<span class="price">$2,000</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

then use  `getElementsByClassName("price")[0]` it will work for the first element only

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".price" ).first().text( "your text" );
```

Please take a look at this [.first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

using javascript

```
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0]
parentElement.innerText="your price"
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention jquery

Comment: Well, it would be OK if it worked, but ".price" isn't going to find it

Comment: why? it would not be?

Comment: `.price` is a jquery format for finding `class="price"`, in the same way `#price` would find `id="price"`. Doesn't work like that for vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

Try getElementById("product-price-27")

Answer (score 0):

If is the first element with the class `price` on your code:

```
var myelement=document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0];
myelement.innerHTML='new content';
```

If you are not sure if it will be the first BUT you know the actual value, you could:

```
var actualValue='whatever';
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('price');
for (var i in elements){
    if (elements[i].innerHTML==actualValue)
    {
        elements[i].innerHTML=newValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here It is, check the

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
 x[0].innerHTML = "$2000";


http://jsfiddle.net/kushalraid/mjVH8/
```